# After insert trigger on a table that has a Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, triggers, primary-key

I have the following 2 tables:

1. `Order` with the following columns: `OrderID` as PK, `Order Name`, etc.
2. `Delivery` with the following columns: `DeliveryID` as PK, `OrderID`, `date`, etc.

I wrote after update trigger on the `Order` table that inserts a new row to the `Delivery` table and fills it with the `OrderID`:

```
create Trigger CopyOrderID_To_DeliveryTable
on Order
for insert 
as 
begin
    declare @ID int

    select @ID = REQUESTID from inserted  

    insert into Delivery (OrderID) 
    values (@ID)
end
```

This should work fine but the issue here is that the `DeliveryID` column in the `Delivery` table is a non-nullable PK. So whenever I try to update the `Order` table, I get an error message that `DeliveryID` in the `Delivery` table doesn’t allow nulls!

How to get rid of this message without altering the `DeliveryID` column?

A screenshot shows the `DeliveryID` column properties :

[image]

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Why are you inserting a record to `Delivery` automatically?

Comment: BC I have orders needs to be delivered  multiple times.